# Getting Proper Type Inference for a more complicated type in a Generic Method

Tags: c#, type-inference, generics

I am working in the .NET 2.0 framework. I have some code working, just want it working a little more elegantly.

I have a need to effectively "mirror" a Dictionary object such that if we start with an object like this

```
Dictionary<TKey,TValue> StartDictionary;
```

We can Mirror it like this

```
Dictionary<TValue,TKey> MirroredDictionary = MirrorDictionary(StartDictionary);
```

And we would end up with a new dictionary with the values and keys being swapped for each KeyValuePair

Before anyone asks me why: the source dictionary is fairly large and loaded once from reflection calls when my program loads. I don't want to run the same reflection calls a second time to load the mirrored dictionary. Creating a mirrored Dictionary and populating its values and keys the way I came up with seemed to me to be much less costly.

So being the kind of person that hates to rewrite things, I decided to write a Generic method in a helper class I have to do the Mirror using Generics.

Now mind you I've written simple Generic methods before for normal scalar types

Here's what I came up with

```
 public static TOutDic MirrorDictionary<TInDic, TOutDic>(TInDic InDictionary)
  where TInDic : IDictionary
  where TOutDic : IDictionary
{
  Type[] KVPTypes = typeof(TInDic).GetGenericArguments();
  Type TKey = KVPTypes[0];
  Type TValue = KVPTypes[1];
  Type TDic = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(TValue, TKey);
  IDictionary OutDic = (IDictionary)Activator.CreateInstance(TDic);
  foreach (DictionaryEntry DE in (IDictionary)InDictionary) OutDic.Add(DE.Value, DE.Key);
  return (TOutDic)OutDic;
}
```

A little bit there but it works, Loads up the Types of the Keys and Values and creates an instance of the mirrored Dictionary

Then just looping through the base DictionaryEntries of the InDictionary it adds the items to the OutDic and returns it casting it to the Type expected

Compiles just fine

Now when i go to call it I would think just like when i call a Generic method for a scalar type I could just using our code snippits above say

```
Dictionary<TValue,TKey> MirroredDictionary = MirrorDictionary(StartDictionary);
```

But that does not compile gives me

> The type arguments for method MirrorDictionary(TInDic)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

So If I call it instead like this

```
      Dictionary<TValue, TKey> MirrorDic = MirrorDictionary<Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>, Dictionary<TValue,TKey>>(StringDic);
```

It compiles and works like a charm.

Now the question becomes how do I make it properly infer the Type being passed into this method when the Type being passed in and the Type being passed out are complex types like in this example?

Comment: How can it infer TOutDic when the input parameter only supplies TInDic type information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make life much easier for the compiler by telling it the key and value types thus:

```
public static Dictionary<TValue, TKey> MirrorDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    (Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
{
    Dictionary<TValue, TKey> destination = new Dictionary<TValue, TKey>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in source)
    {
        destination.Add(kvp.Value, kvp.Key);
    }

    return destination;
}
```

I don't think you need reflection here at all.

Sample usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> source = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    source.Add(3, "foo");
    source.Add(4, "bar");

    DumpDic(source);

    DumpDic(MirrorDictionary(source));

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

where `DumpDic` is:

```
public static void DumpDic<TK, TV>(Dictionary<TK, TV> dic)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<TK, TV> keyValuePair in dic)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that first it would not compile for me for some reason Let me go back and retry it maybe i messed up when i was creating the method the first time. I'll repost when I've tested

Comment: Yep completely rushed over the method declaration and forgot to declare my types so i had public static Dictionary<TValue, TKey> MirrorDictionary(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> InDictionary) when i needed public static Dictionary<TValue, TKey> MirrorDictionary<TKey,TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> InDictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 3.5 solution (you can also use it in 2.0 with VS2008 and LinqBridge)

```
IDictionary<TValue, TKey> MirrorDictionary<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
{
    return dict.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => kvp.Key);
}
```

And a pure 2.0 solution

```
IDictionary<TValue, TKey> MirrorDictionary<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
{
    Dictionary<TValue, TKey> newDict = new Dictionary<TValue, TKey>();
    foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in dict)
    {
        newDict.Add(kvp.Value, kvp.Key);
    }
    return newDict;
}
```

Type inference should work fine with both solutions (as they have the same signature)

Comment: As well as avoiding reflection, this also enforces that the input and output types are correct. There's nothing to stop you calling the original method as `MirrorDictionary<Dictionary<int,string>,Dictionary<Guid,bool>>(input)`, and it'll compile fine but blow up with an invalid cast at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the Out dictionary as an `out` parameter. Type inference does not look the type of the variable you're assigning to, only the types of the parameters. That's the reason this doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it what TValue and TKey are. Unless they are defined up in the signature of the method calling this code, they don't have any specific types. You need to give it something like:

```
Dictionary<string, int> MirroredDictionary = MirrorDictionary(StartDictionary);
```

Comment: This doesn't help the compiler infer the type of TOutDic, and this line gives the same compiler error.

Comment: @stevemegson - No, upon reading further it doesn't even come close, I was tempted to delete it, but after the downvote I wanted leave it to give someone a chance to comment.

Comment: I'll retract the downvote then, I only bothered to downvote because the single upvote made it the top answer at the time.

Comment: @stevemegson - the upvote should removed as well, but I'll leave it up as an example of how not to answer.